# How to Start app using Broadcast Receiver in android 6 which doesn't have permission

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

How to start my app when call comes to my mobile. Broadcast receiver won't work as my app was not running earlier and i didn't have permission to check android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE in android 6.0(Marshmallow).

I don't have any activity class. I just wanted to create a txt file when a call comes.

I just want to know how can we get permission for broadcast receiver when app has not yet started. when call comes broadcast will not work as we doesn't have the permission.

Here is my code:

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ranveer.teaser">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name=".IncommingCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**IncommingCallReceiver.java**

```
 package com.example.ranveer.teaser;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
    import java.io.*;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    public class IncommingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
    {
        public IncommingCallReceiver() 
        {
        }
        Context mContext;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent)
        {
            try{
             File file = new File("Hello1.txt");
             file.createNewFile();
              FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        // Writes the content to the file
        writer.write("This\n is\n an\n example\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Done writing in file",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

            try
            {

                String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);



                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Phone Is Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Your Code
                }

                if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Call Recieved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Your Code
                }

                if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
                {

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Phone Is Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // Your Code

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                //your custom message
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You need an `Activity`. That's just how it is.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your app is a system app, you need to have at least one `Activity` and the user needs to explicitly (manually) start your app at least once. Otherwise your app stays in the "stopped state" and your `BroadcastReceiver` will not receive any calls to `onReceive()`. This has been the case since Android 3.0.